# Solr Search for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, search, solr

I have installed the plugin "Solr Search for WordPress" but cannot find any instructions online of how to actually use it.  Does anybody know of a good guide for a novice to Solr on how to use it? Even some basic example would help put me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: So what is your problem? Have you followed [the installation instructions given for the plugin itself](https://nb.wordpress.org/plugins/solr-power/#installation)?

Comment: Yeah its all installed.  I just dont know what todo with it once it is installed.  I asked Pantheon and they said once it is installed it is a wordpress solr/wordpress issue and not theirs.

Comment: When you've installed it, doesn't it just replace your search by going to Solr instead of the regular database? You can then further extend the search by implementing custom templates, etc.?

Comment: yeah its the custom templates that I wanted to know how to build, as I want to be able to give it keywords/taxonomy to bring back certain results.

Comment: Then ask about that, add a proper example what you're trying to, what you've tried to do and why that doesn't work. There are [examples available](https://github.com/substantial/solr-for-wordpress/tree/master/template). Be aware that the plugin hasn't been updated for six years, so the schema will probably need to be changed if you're going to run on Solr 6/7.